# What is wrong with my momentjs sorting (js)?

Tags: javascript, sorting, typescript, momentjs

I am having an array of objects, that I'd like to sort.

I'd like to sort "chunks" by first trip, and inside the "chunk", trips should be sorted by date 'in'.

The second part is working as expected, but the map() is not.

So my chunk are ordered by first trip date, but not trips.

nb: chunks are made via lodash. So I could use this library if any solution with it.

```
  sortByChunkAndTrip(chunkedTrip: Array<{ trips: Trip[], chunk: string }>): Array<{ trips: Trip[], chunk: string }> {
    return chunkedTrip
      .map(chunkItem => {
        const sortedTrips = chunkItem.trips.sort((left, right) => {
          const leftMoment = moment(left.in);
          const rightMoment = moment(right.in);
          return leftMoment.diff(rightMoment);
        })
        return {
          chunk: chunkItem.chunk,
          trips: sortedTrips
        };
      })
    .sort((a, b) => {
     // working as expected
      const aMoment = moment(a.trips[0].in);
      const bMoment = moment(b.trips[0].in);
      return bMoment.diff(aMoment, 'days');
    })

  }
```

Comment: Sort callback methods should return true and false. That will decide whether to shift the element or not. In your case your are returning a value which will be always true. Incase of returning numbers, 0 is considered false and rest true

Comment: No it should return a number value => https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort